# C++ class depends on function, but function depends on class

Tags: c++, declaration

I can't compile this code because the function declaration depends on the class declaration, and the class declaration depends on the function declaration.  Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void simulate(Policy& p);

class Policy {
public:
    Policy(int);
    int x;
    void eval();
};

int main() {
    Policy p(23);
    return 0;
}

Policy::Policy(int y) { x = y; }
void Policy::eval() { simulate(this); }

void simulate(Policy& p) { cout << ++p.x << endl; }
```

Comment: I don't see why `simulate` isn't a method in `Policy`...

Comment: @Mike DeSimone Here it should be.  But this is a toy example where I'm planning for another case.  And even in the other case perhaps it ought to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the prototype of your function below the definition of your class, but above the member functions.